# Step By Step how to graph trig from local maxima and minimum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

**Question**

The Secant Graph has the local minimum point at $(-0.75,-1.5)$ and it has a local maximum at $(2.25,-2.5)$

Give the equation in the form: $y=A \sec(Bx+C)+D$

**My thought process&steps until I got stuck**

*First I find the Period*

I do this by finding the horizontal distance from the minimum and maximum and multiply that number by $2$ to get the distance aka the period. that means the distance from the minimum to the maximum is $3$ so the period is $6$.

*Then I find $B$*

As anyone knows, the way you get the period is to do $\frac{2\pi}{B}$ that means $\frac{2\pi}{B}=6$. then we can deduce that $B$ is going to be $\frac{\pi}{3}$. We also recognize the fact that ($\frac{\pi}{3}(x)+c)=0$ sets up the beginning of the primary period.

*Then I find the amplitude*

This fairly easy, i just found it to be $0.5$

*What I have so far*

we have the following right now: $\frac{1}{2}\sec(\frac{\pi}{3}x+C)-2$

Now my question is how to find what is $C$?

After that i plug in -0.75 into the equation as follows:

$\frac{1}{2}\sec(\frac{\pi}{3}(\frac{-3}{4})+C)-2=1.5$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y=\frac12\sec(\frac\pi3x)-2$ has a minimum at $(0,-1.5)$ and a maximum at $(3, -2.5)$. You only need to shift your graph to the left by $0.75$. Hint: To shift a graph to the left by $C$, change $f(x)$ to $f(x+C)$.